# Why is my UIwebView content cut off in iOS?

Tags: css, ios, ipad, mobile, uiwebview

I am developing an app for the Ipad, the whole app is a webView, in which i load a local html.The UIwebView fills the entire xib. The html had a one div with

```
width:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
height:100%;
```

but it is consistently cut off on the right side by 50px or so?

how do i center it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody else is having the same problem, check your xib file. The webview was not sized propperly :)

Comment: That is not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0" />`

Comment: i am voting it up, because it is a very good advice in general, so people can see it. My problem was different.